# Problem with awk and redis and UTF8 charcters

Tags: awk, redis, pipe

I use awk to process a CSV file and then send it to redis-cli --pipe. I use redis-cli version 5.0.5 and awk 4.2.1 on fedora30.

When the CSV file contains special characters such as e.g. "é", then the pipe to redis-cli fails. But only, if there is another column behind it!

I have tested the awk script with various CSV files and it works.

If I replace the problematic character with a "e" then piping works. I have also output the result to the console and can see that awk properly processes the character. I have tried to quote the string and also to escape but nothing worked.

The CSV file is in UTF8 format.

Here is the CSV - columns separated by TAB:

```
geonameid name description
2994701 Roc Melé Test
```

Awk script (excerpt):

```
...
result= result "$" length(keys[i]) "\r\n" keys[i] "\r\n"
result= result "$" length(values[i]) "\r\n" values[i] "\r\n"
...
```

Awk script makes this out of a CSV line (according to redis protocol):

```
*8
$5
HMSET
$16
geonames:2994701
$9
geonameid
$7
2994701
$4
name
$8
Rock Melé
$11
description
$4
Test
```

I run the awk script and pipe like this:

```
awk -f csv2redis.awk test.csv | redis-cli --pipe
```

.. and it fails.

But if I remove the last column (description) and the value it works:

```
*6
$5
HMSET
$16
geonames:2994701
$9
geonameid
$7
2994701
$4
name
$8
Rock Melé
```

Expected result is that the redis-client should accept data containing these types of characters.

The error message from redis - if I use one of those characters - is:

```
All data transferred. Waiting for last reply...
ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ' '
```

I check redis after I ran it and it did not transfer any data.

In the case when it works as described above then I see this in redis:

```
1) geonameid
2) 2994701
3) name
4) Roc Mel\xc3
```

Comment: Have you got your locale set correctly? https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/n3zERgnu50I

Comment: I think so. All set to
    de_CH.UTF-8

Comment: I snuffled around some more and found the same symptoms again here... https://grokbase.com/t/gg/redis-db/126enqgxd9/mass-insertion-utf-8

Comment: If radis-cli expects the number of bytes you can use the awk -b switch. (this way locales are ignored).

Comment: Thanks a lot Casimir - the -b switch did the trick.

Comment: I updated my awk script. It is available here:

https://github.com/uwegeercken/awk_scripts/blob/master/csv2redis.awk

I also added a note about the -b flag.

Comment: Thanks to Mark as well for helping and taking the time to respond

Comment: Well done for working it out. Add your code as the answer and accept it as correct to share your work with the SO community and bag the points too.

Comment: Mark, how do I do that??

Comment: @uwegeercken: Fill in "Your answer" (below). Include your code. Click the check mark next to your answer; this shows everyone it's the accepted answer. (You can change that at any time.)